# How to find and replace values in one dictionary based on another

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dictionary, replace

I have two dictionaries, let's say these are `regex = {}` and `dict = {}`.

First of them contains find and replace patterns respectively as `keys` and `values`. So it looks like this:

```
# about 50 key/value pairs
regex = {
    'find1' : 'replace1',
    'find2' : 'replace2',
    ...
    'findX' : 'replaceX'
}
```

The second one looks like this:

```
# about 500,000 key/value pairs
dict = {
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2',
    ...
    'keyX' : 'valueX'
}
```

For every `keyX`, `valueX` from `dict` I want to check, if the `valueX` includes `findX` from `regex`, if yes, I want to replace it with `replaceX` and save into the same (`dict`) or new dictionary or list (used a new list in the code below).

I've tried with this code:

```
for keyX, valueX in dict.items():
    for patterns in regex.items():
        if re.search(patterns[0], valueX)
            new_value = re.sub(patterns[0], patterns[1], valueX)

    new_line = keyX + '\t' + new_value

    new_list.append(new_line)
```

My mechanism works wrong: for every `valueX` it should check if it contains any of every `findX`, replace it with `replaceX`, save, but instead I am getting quite a mess in the output list. Duplicate `new_value`s for different `keyX`s. I am aware that there's something wrong with iterating over my dictionaries (probably the regex dictionary), but I have no idea, how to fix this.

---

EDIT (examples):

```
regex = {
   's t n': 's n',
   'e0': 'i0',
   'j a0': 'j i0'
}

dict = {
    'известный': 'i0 z vj e1 s t n y0 j',
    'сестра': 'sj e0 s t r a1'
    'январь': 'j a0 n v a1 rj'
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of `dict` and `regex` and the result you want to achieve.

Comment: Moreover, what do you mean by _I want to check, if the valueX includes findX from regex_? Are values in the `dict` dictionary single words or mutliple words?

Comment: @sentence, examples are above. As a result I want, let's say, list with `dict`'s keys and values, but values with some patterns replaced, for instance 'известный': 'i0 z vj e1 s n y0 j' ('stn' changed to 'sn'). There can be more than 1 replaces per value, which means I want to implement every find/replace pattern for every `dict` value.

Comment: Values in the `dict` are multiple 1-2 character groups, so basically -- they are multiple "words", from the programming perspective, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
regex = {
   's t n': 's n',
   'e0': 'i0',
   'j a0': 'j i0'
}

dict = {
    'известный': 'i0 z vj e1 s t n y0 j',
    'сестра': 'sj e0 s t r a1',
    'январь': 'j a0 n v a1 rj'
}
for k1,v1 in regex.items():
    for k2,v2 in dict.items():
        if k1 in v2:
            dict[k2]=dict[k2].replace(k1,v1)
```

And you get:

```
dict

{'известный': 'i0 z vj e1 s n y0 j',
 'сестра': 'sj i0 s t r a1',
 'январь': 'j i0 n v a1 rj'}
```

Comment: I didn't know that `if k1 in v2` can work as a search tool for strings. Thx.

Comment: If I could extend this question, what about using some real RegEx inside the first dict, for instance, adding something like this:
    `'([bvgdzklmnprstfh])j a0': '\\1j i0'`,
to be applied in `'приколотят': 'p rj i0 k a0 l o1 tj a0 t'` in the second dict,
resulting with:
p rj i0 k a0 l o1 tj i0 t
? I can't get this working.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the keys and the organize them a list of tuples that you later loop and replace accordingly your values, like the following:

```
# init vars
regex = {'s t n': 's n', 'e0': 'i0', 'j a0': 'j i0'}
d = {'известный': 'i0 z vj e1 s t n y0 j', 'сестра': 'sj e0 s t r a1', 'январь': 'j a0 n v a1 rj'}
# debug prints
print(regex)
print(d)
# get keys for replacements
import itertools
tuples = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[(keyx, findx) for keyx in d.keys() if findx in d[keyx]] for findx in regex.keys()]))
# loop and replace
for keyx, findx in tuples:
    d[keyx] = d[keyx].replace(findx, regex[findx])
# print output
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'s t n': 's n', 'e0': 'i0', 'j a0': 'j i0'}
{'известный': 'i0 z vj e1 s t n y0 j', 'сестра': 'sj e0 s t r a1', 'январь': 'j a0 n v a1 rj'}
{'известный': 'i0 z vj e1 s n y0 j', 'сестра': 'sj i0 s t r a1', 'январь': 'j i0 n v a1 rj'}
```